# Why is the validation accuracy in Siamese Network is not going above 0.5 but the training accuracy is becoming >0.9?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, siamese-network

I was trying to implement Siamese networks in this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/shrutisaxena/yoga-pose-image-classification-dataset). AS I wrote in the title, no matter how I change my code, the validation accuracy is going to 0.9 in 6-7 epochs but the test accuracy or loss is not improving. What should I do?

The code for generation of my network:

```
def gen():
   i = Input(shape = (100, 100, 1))
   mod = Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation= 'relu')(i)
   mod = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3))(mod)
   mod = Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation= 'relu')(mod)
   mod = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3))(mod)
   mod = BatchNormalization()(mod)
   mod = Conv2D(128, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation= 'relu')(mod)
   mod = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3))(mod)
   mod = Flatten()(mod)
   mod = Dense(256, activation= 'relu')(mod)
   return (mod, i)
(left_side, left_input) = gen()
(right_side, right_input) = gen()
L1_layer = lambda tensors: K.abs(tensors[0] - tensors[1])
L1_distance = L1_layer([left_side, right_side])
prediction = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(L1_distance)
net = Model([left_input, right_input], prediction)
```

The negative and positive pairs are arranged alternatively. I am training 8000 images. I tried with 40000 images but still got the same results
I have changed the number of layers, number of units in each layer, size of dataset, converted colour images to greyscale so that i can put more images in my ram to train, changed the learning rate etc, but the result is the same. The model trains well, but the validation accuracy is always around 0.5. What should I do?

Comment: Can you remove batchnormalization and test again? It is often some form of a bug with use of BN.

Comment: did that and still didn't work

Comment: How do you load the generators? Can you provide that code?